# Tshark - Some fields aren't valid

Tags: bash, wireshark, tshark

I'm trying to generate a json file from a .pcap witth only a few fields. The first thing I'm doing is exporting the whole .pcap as a json file to see the fields I want to extract (File - Export Packet Dissections - As json). Then I execute tshark with the next sintax:

tshark -r example.pcap -T json > example.json -e ip.dst -e ip.src -e gsm_map.ms.sai_Present

And the result of the last command is:

**Tshark - Some fields aren't valid:** gsm_map.ms.sai_Present

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wireshark's online [Display Filter Reference page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/g/gsm_map.html), the `gsm_map.ms.sai_Present` field was only present in Wireshark versions 1.0.0 to 1.10.14.  Perhaps you're looking for `gsm_map.ms.sai_Present_element` now?

Comment: Not at all, when I export the pcap as json format that field exists. Even i can see in the wireshark program. However, I think that field is not supported by the tshark version I'm using

Comment: *"Even i can see in the wireshark program"*.  Where do you see that?  The name of the display filter is **definitely** `gsm_map.ms.sai_Present_element`, as can be seen around line 28728 of the packet-gsm_map.c file here: https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-gsm_map.c.  Maybe you are confusing the display filter with the *"sai-Present"* text that's displayed?

Comment: It's much easier to browse the source code online in the old repo, although keep in mind it's not the latest code anymore.  But compare https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gsm_map.c;h=a08b0ec8e6216e72b831cd266f3aa9ab6f3effe7;hb=HEAD#l28277 with the master-1.0 source code at https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gsm_map.c;h=eb60b058fff5ea3b7a34fed24f376630e002ef74;hb=refs/heads/master-1.0#l20092 and you'll clearly see the difference in the display filter name.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christopher Maynard. Another doubt, where can I find the code that wireshark is using to see all the variables and values that they assign. Could I see in a .py? Thanks in advance

Comment: I provided a link to the Wireshark source code.  It is largely written in C and C++, not Python.  If you're interested in building Wireshark itself, then I'd suggest reading the Wireshark Developer's Guide at: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/, or if you're just interested in downloading the source code, then refer to section 3.4 of the Developer Guide: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSrcObtain.html.